# VueJS conditional sort data to table

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, vue.js, vuejs2

I have data of hotels listing, i need to create table with two columns: in first column others hosts listing, in second column listing of my hotels. I can check it by parameter - client_listing (0 or 1).

But if i'm using v-if it does not create second column it just sckip and place my hotels to first (right column) as result - all listings in one column.

What i want: 
[image]

What i get: 
[image]

My code:

```
<div class="date-card col-md-6" v-for="dateCard in calendarResults.calendar_results" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
  <div class="date-card-header"><h3>{{dateCard.checkin.$date | moment("MM/DD/YYYY (dddd)")}}</h3></div>

  <div class="date-card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered b-t">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Others</th>
          <th>My</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="result in dateCard.results">
          <td style="width: 50%" v-if="result.client_listing === 0">Others</td>
          <td style="width: 50%" v-if="result.client_listing === 1">My</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i'm doing wrong? How to achieve result?

Comment: Is that vanilla bootstrap or vue-bootstrap?

Comment: @Deda Yep, i think it skip creation of first td if client_listing = 1 and because of it, all goes to single column. But i can't figure out how to create blank td in left column if client_listing = 1

Comment: I think you'll need two inline tables for this. Otherwise the formatting will not be good.

Comment: @BTL but how to handle this loop - v-for="result in dateCard.results"

Comment: You create 2 computed methods who filters the results : 
`others () {
      return this.dateCard.results.filter(result => result.client_listing === 0)
    }`
And you loop over each filtered array in each table

Comment: @BTL but i have more complex structure of my data - https://yadi.sk/i/oiCnNYluxONE0w and get Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. How i can loop inside calendar_results.results in computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not perfect solution, but working for me:

```
<table class="table  b-t">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Others</th>
      <th>My</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%">
        <ul>
          <template v-for="result in dateCard.results">
            <template v-if="result.client_listing === 0">
              <li>OTHER</li>
            </template>
            <template v-else="">
            </template>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="client-listing" style="width: 50%">
        <ul>
          <template v-for="result in dateCard.results">
            <template v-if="result.client_listing === 1">
              <li>MY</li>
            </template>
            <template v-else="">
            </template>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why all goes into single column is that your code makes a single td element with every loop. But on the other hand, if you make 2 td elements with one blank, you'll end up with little "holes" in the table. Here is a workaround with the computed method.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dateCard : {
      results : [
        {client_listing : 0, price: 23},
        {client_listing : 1, price: 32},
        {client_listing : 0, price: 51},
        {client_listing : 0, price: 62},
        {client_listing : 1, price: 73}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: { 
    sortListings(){
      let listingOne = this.dateCard.results.filter(result=>result.client_listing === 0)
      let listingTwo = this.dateCard.results.filter(result=>result.client_listing === 1)
      let maxLength = listingOne.length > listingTwo.length ? listingOne : listingTwo
      return { listingOne, listingTwo, maxLength   }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="date-card-body">
  <table class="table table-bordered b-t">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Others</th>
        <th>My</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(result, index) in sortListings.maxLength">
        <td v-if="sortListings.listingOne[index]" style="width: 50%" >{{sortListings.listingOne[index].price}}</td>
        <td v-if="sortListings.listingTwo[index]" style="width: 50%" >{{sortListings.listingTwo[index].price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i have one more nested level (update code in question). From mondoDB https://yadi.sk/i/oiCnNYluxONE0w

Comment: Just make `sortListings` takes a parameter `results`, and change `this.dateCard.results` into `results`, in template change `v-for="(result, index) in sortListings.maxLength"` in `v-for="(result, index) in sortListings(dataCard.results)"`, and it should work.

Comment: results.filter is not a function

Comment: as i can understand, i can't pass params to computed func